# Find $z^n$ for (a) $z = 3+4i$ (b) $z=i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm given to find $z^n$ for

(a) $z = 3+4i$

(b) $z=i$.

I just want to ask that as there's no instructions given should I do it by converting $z$ into it's polar form? And after computing $z^n$ do I need to convert it back to it's Cartesian form?

(In case of (b) it's pretty easy so give me your opinion about (a))

Thank you.

Comment: yes, convert to polar form for sure. (b) has a simple pattern. The form you give the answer in is irrelevant if it's not specifed.

Comment: @Henno thanks. But I'm having a trouble here will you help me? For case (a) I found that $\cos \theta = \frac{3}{5}$ and $\sin \theta = \frac{4}{5}$. From here how can I find $\theta$ so that I can use *de-Moivre's*?

Comment: So what is $\theta$? You know its sine and cosine so you know what it is.

Comment: Then $\theta$ can be written as $ \theta = \arctan{\frac{4}{3}}$. But from here if I use *de-Moivre's* I'm getting $z^n = 5^{50} [ \cos (50 \arctan{\frac{4}{3}}) + i \sin (50 \arctan{\frac{4}{3}})]$. But can it get more simplified?

Comment: It's an exact form so it need not be simplified. You compute only $z^{50}$ BTW.

Comment: Okay thanks. I am not being able to write arc tan properly. I used *\arctan{\frac{4}{3}}*. Is it wrong?

Comment: `$\arctan(\frac{4}{3})$` gives $\arctan(\frac{4}{3})$ no braces for arctan arguments.

Comment: Okay so it's not for writing it as $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't like writing $\tan^{-1}$ anyway. Imprecise notation.

Answer (score 2):

Hint #1: Find the modulus (absolute value) and angle of $z$, i.e. $$|z| = \sqrt {a^2+b^2}$$ and $$\theta = \arctan \frac {b}{a}$$

Hint #2: Plug the values you found in Hint #1 into DeMoivre's Theorem:  $$z^n = |z|^n (\cos n \theta + i \sin n \theta)$$

Hint #3: Use the multiple angle formulas to convert the polar forms into rectangular forms.